# [AWS]Get clouffront redirecting to the right apache vhost instead of default one

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have set a cloudfront distribution with an orgin which is a vhost on apache.

When I select "**None (Improve Caching)**" in the **Forward Hearder** option, the **cname** of the cloudfront distribution sends me to my default vhost (the **"It works"** page) instead of my origin domain name.

But If I whilist **Host** header for exemple, I get to vhost hosting my origin domain name

But I saw some other distribution which have no header forwarded and working fine.

I just want someone to confirm if today in aws, to have cloudfront redirecting request to the right vhost on the origin server, we need to whilelist **HOST** header in the "**Forward Headers**" option.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm, we need tho whilist **Host** header to get cloudfront redirect to the right vhost on the origin server.

Regards.